# How to estimate variance of underlying noise?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, python, polynomial

I am a beginner to Machine Learning in Python. I have been given set of corresponding values for y and x such that y is a polynomial of an unknown degree in x. Additionally, in the provided data, Gaussian noise of zero mean and an unknown variance has been added, so the y values that are given to me are actually y=f(x) + E (where E is the added Gaussian noise). Is there a way to find the variance for this underlying noise(for instance, any in-built function in python)? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First you need to estimate f, when you know it you can simply take the residual variance (assuming heteroscedasticity). If you can't learn f, not much can be done (consider extreme cases like f(x)=0 that leads to zero variance, or f(x) that returns a random value).

Comment: I have found the degree and the coefficients for which I get the best fit.

Comment: The best fit is not a good criterion to select the degree. You will [overfit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model is

$$
y_i = f(X_i) + \varepsilon_i
$$

with Gaussian noise $\varepsilon_i$ having mean zero and unknown variance $\sigma^2$, then it translates to

$$
y_i | X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(f(X_i), \sigma^2)
$$

then to calculate the variance of residuals (there is a distinction between [error and residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals)), you would first need to estimate the mean of the conditional distribution $E(Y|X) = f(X)$, since variance is the squared distance from the mean. To find $E(Y) = E_X(E_Y(Y|X)) = E_X(f(X)) \approx \hat f(X)$. Then you can simply substitute

$$
\newcommand{Var}{\mathrm{Var}}
\Var(Y) = E[(Y - E(Y))^2]
$$

with

$$
\widehat{\Var}(Y) = \mathrm{mean}((Y - \hat f(X))^2)
$$

where $\hat f(X)$ is your estimate of $E(f(X))$.

TLDR; You need to  estimate $f(X)$ and then calculate the variance of residuals and this will be your estimate of the variance.

Comment: Do you assume that $Var(Y) = \sigma^2$? If so, I fail to see how that is. My understanding that the OP needs to know how to find an estimate for $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @rando no I'm not, but the question does not ask about the unconditional variance of $Y$.

Comment: I haven't really caught on how to estimate $\sigma$ based on $Var(Y)$?